# Rules with regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I want to check if a sentence matches one of these patterns:

```
[iI]t(\w*\s)?((is)|(became))\s((clear)|(possible)|(important)|(necessary))(to)?
```

Example of sentences:

```
It is important to note...
It became clear that...
```

I tried on a file that contains this structure, but it doesn't give a result.

So, I want to know if my regular expression is correct or not.

Comment: Pay attention to the round brackets, there is a mismatch in their order. `became))`... `((clear`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the opening and the closing parenthesis

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact code you're using instead of composing it in the question box. That will save everybody time.

Comment: Your regex works on both example strings you showed. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you're using and why you think it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten a space before `to`:

```
[iI]t(\w*\s)?((is)|(became))\s((clear)|(possible)|(important)|(necessary))\s*(to)?   
                                                                   here __^^^
```

Are you sure you want to capture all the words? If not, the regex could be:

```
[iI]t\w*\s(?:is|became)\s(?:clear|possible|important|necessary)\s*(?:to)?
```

Comment: The `to` is optional, so the OP's regex works as-is on both example strings they gave.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OP's regex as-is works but doesn't capture `to` for the first string as they missed `\s*`

Comment: @Orions That's fine, but that's not the problem they described. Actually, the only explanation they gave was "it doesn't give a result," which is vague enough that the question really shouldn't be answered until they've added their code and explained what the actual problem is. It's not even clear that they want to capture anything at all, since they just say they want to "check if a sentence *matches*."